# monitoring organisation in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can we monitor the changes done at organisation policy level in GCP. Want to know if one org admin makes change in the org level policies then it should be known to other org admin on real time basis. So can we set the alerts for such org level changes in gcp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to the organization logs only with the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read). To see what happens on your organization, you can check the [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit) like this

```
gcloud logging read --organization=ORGANIZARION_NUMBER \
   protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
```

You can narrow your search on the elements that you look for. Then, you can create a [sink into Pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/sinks/create). And plug what you want on it (we usually plug a Cloud Functions, but a Cloud Run service also work)

Comment: Thanks , will try the same